# Stdin and stdout redirection

Tags: linux, bash

There is a statement

> stty onlcr 0>&1

in rc.sysvinit file. What does exactly this line do? What's the reason for redirecting stdin to stdout?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ man stty
...
   * [-]onlcr
          translate newline to carriage return-newline
...
```

and there's even a comment in the file, which you failed to mention:

```
# Set onlcr to avoid staircase effect.
```

So that should make it clear what the line does. `stty` operates on `stdin` by default, but this line changes output settings, so `0>&1` makes it work on `stdout`. Which can actually matter if you've a box where the console stdout is hooked up to one serial port, and the console stdin input to some other source ...

**Edit**

`stty` changes terminal parameters. To do so, it must issue system calls which operate on a file handle that correspond to a terminal. By default, this is `stdin`, as the manpage says:

```
  -F, --file=DEVICE
          open and use the specified DEVICE instead of stdin
```

I'm not sure what kind of example would help you ...

Comment: What do you mean "stty operates on stdin by default"? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can You answer my last question please?

Comment: I tried to answer the question with the edit. Which part of the edit is not clear? What kind of examples do you think you need? Do you understand the concept of Unix tty's, and that `stty` changes parameters for them?

Comment: How does stdin relates to dev/tty1, dev/tty2 ...?.

Comment: Do you understand what stdin and stdout mean? When a process is executed on Unix, what can a process assume about stdin and stdout, and who decides where stdin and stdout point to?

Comment: Am i right that when i'm on tty1 terminal (as showed by tty command) the tty1 is the current, default stdin, stdout and stderr and every process i start would have an tty1 linked to it?

Comment: No, you are not right. For starters, the concept of "I am on tty1 terminal" doesn't exist. Also, the executing process determines stdin and stdout, and they'll be different when redirected (e.g. `cat /some/file | process > /someother/file`: what are stdin and stdout for `process`?). And now imagine an old-school Unix system where **for the console environment** (which is where run level messages appear), stdout is connected to a parallel port printer, and stdin is connected to a teletype keyboard via a serial port.

Comment: So how does stdin, stdout and stderr relates to dev/tty1, dev/tty2

Comment: If you don't understand stdin/stdout etc., and why they can point to various files or devices (or ttys), I guess that's a new question...

Comment: The doc says: "The stty utility sets and/or reports terminal I/O characteristics for the device that is its standard input". So when i isue stty when i'm sitting on tty1 the tty1 is current input and i'm changing settings for tty1?

Comment: Can You answer my last question?

Comment: As long as you insist that "sitting on tty1" with a shell where stdin and stdout both point to /dev/tty1 is all there is, you won't understand why `0>&1` is needed and what it does. You will need to admit that there are other situations, that the stdin/stdout mechanism is more general, and I've already explained that and given examples. We are going in circles. Yes, and obviously when stdin points to tty1, and you are using stty without any options or redirection, you are changing the settings of tty1 (what else?). But that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you type `man stty` you'll get the documentation for `stty`, which among other things says

> `[-]onlcr` translate newline to carriage return-newline

The reason for the redirection is that `stty` operates on its *stdin*, but there's only *stdout* available at the time the command is run.

Comment: "stty operates on its stdin, but there's only stdout available at the time the command is run" - can You explain me that more?

Comment: Can You answer my last question?

Comment: @Ringger81 which bit is unclear?